# How do i insert a different column from a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a two tables that look like this: [image]

Now to connect two client i need their id, but i'm getting their names instead.

Is there a way of doing it without running a query for each id, and than a final third query to create the connection,

or a better way than doing this:

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2) VALUES (
(SELECT id FROM clients WHERE name='name1'),
(SELECT id FROM clients WHERE name='name2')
)
```

If there is something i'm missing than please let me know.

Comment: If the names don't match, then you'll get `NULL`.  Is that a requirement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No it is not

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much instead of two queries, you can do one
using  cross join  and an insert select

```
  insert client_conn (c1, c2) 
  select  a.id, b.id 
  from  clients a 
  cross join clients b
  where a.name  = 'name1'
    and b.name  ='name2'
```

Comment: A `cross join` will potentially generate a very long list which is then narrowed down by the `where` clause. I don't know but I suspect, that this solution will *not* be more efficient than the statement provided by OP.

Comment: @cars10m . . . Not at all.  The two tables are filtered, so only one row (at most) is processed from each table.

Answer (score 1):

One way or the other, if what you have is the names you're going to have to query the table to get the associated IDs. I suggest you use a self-join:

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2)
  SELECT c1.id, c2.id
    FROM clients c1
    INNER JOIN clients c2
      ON c2.name = 'Barney'
    WHERE c1.name = 'Fred';
```

If both names exist you'll insert the associated ID's into `client_conn`. If either or both don't exist nothing will be inserted.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d22dddc40c7b6d473c98c932400966fb)

### EDIT

If by chance you decide that you *do* want NULL values added if the matching names don't exist in `clients` there's a couple things your can do:

If you're OK with inserting a row if *both* names are missing you can use

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2)
  SELECT c1.id, c2.id
    FROM (SELECT 1) x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c1
      ON c1.name = 'Betty'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c2
      ON c2.name = 'Wilma'
```

This will always insert a row, even if neither of the names match a 'clients' row. If you want to insist that at least one of the names match you can add a WHERE clause, as in:

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2)
  SELECT c1.id, c2.id
    FROM (SELECT 1) x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c1
      ON c1.name = 'Pebbles'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c2
      ON c2.name = 'Bam-Bam'
    WHERE c1.name IS NOT NULL OR
          c2.name IS NOT NULL
```

The above will insert nothing because neither Pebbles or Bam-Bam exist in the `clients` table, but

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2)
  SELECT c1.id, c2.id
    FROM (SELECT 1) x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c1
      ON c1.name = 'Fred'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c2
      ON c2.name = 'Bam-Bam'
    WHERE c1.name IS NOT NULL OR
          c2.name IS NOT NULL
```

will insert a row.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed0332088a62079b28f5250ab693b558)

Answer (score 0):

I think Bob Jarvis has the best answer for the on-off immediate case. For readability/maintainability and possibly a speed boost if this ever got sufficiently large is to make a dedicated function for this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION client_id(p_name varchar) RETURNS integer AS $$
  SELECT id FROM clients AS c WHERE c.name = p_name;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT STABLE LEAKPROOF PARALLEL SAFE;
```

This makes the insert nicer to look at and more understandable at a glance.

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2) VALUES
(client_id('name1'), client_id('name2'));
```

The speed boost would come into play if you were inserting several items that shared the same ids.

```
INSERT INTO client_conn (c1, c2) VALUES
(client_id('name1'), client_id('name2')),
(client_id('name1'), client_id('name3')),
(client_id('name1'), client_id('name4'));
```

Because the function is marked `STABLE` and only calls `SELECT`, PostgreSQL can optimize the call away after the first time. So instead of six separate `SELECT`s, PostgreSQL can get away with just four since it knows 'name1' will always return the same id each time during the transaction.